# Laplace transform and delay

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

Hi guys if i have to transform $e^{t-1}u(t-1)$ , why the result is $\frac{e^{-s}}{(s-1)}$ and not $\frac{e^{-(s-1)}}{(s-1)}$  if the $e^{t-1}$ multiply all the "function" ?

Comment: What is $u$ here?

Comment: is the step function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${\cal L}\left(u(t-c)f(t-c)\right)=e^{-cs}{\cal L}(f)$$
now let $c=1$:
$${\cal L}\left(u(t-1)e^{t-1}\right)=e^{-s}\dfrac{1}{s-1}$$

Comment: so after i have multiplied by $e^{-cs}$ i only have to make the transorm as it was f(t) and not f(t-c) ? so in my example i have to make the transform of $e^{t}u(t)$ as if this was my transform and after all multiply by $e^{-1s}$ ?

Comment: first statement is 'yes'. I don't understand the second. sorry :)